# Using a file containing a matrix to print a list

Tags: python

I have a score_matrix.txt file which contains:

```
6,1,2,-10
1,5,0,-2
2,0,6,3
-10,-2,3,5
```

I'm trying to code a function "read_scores" that consumes a file name (string) as its parameter and returns a list of list of ints (4x4 matrix).

This is what I have:

```
def read_scores(file)
    file=open('score_matrix.txt')
    g=[]
    for aline in file:
        aline=float(aline)
        g[aline]=aline.split('/n')
    return g
```

Comment: Does your solution work? If not how is it deficient? Does it produce exceptions?

Comment: To read CSV data, it's a good idea it use [the csv module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and save yourself some reinventing of the wheel.

Comment: Why are you trying to do `aline.split('/n')`? That isn't going to do anything (even if you meant `'\n'`, there are no newlines within each line), but without knowing what it was _intended_ to do, it's hard to explain how to fix it. And likewise for `g[aline]`—trying to use a line (a string) as an index into an empty array obviously won't work, but without knowing what it was supposed to do (maybe `g.append`?), it's hard to explain how to do what you intended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`map()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) with [`split(',')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
with open('test.txt') as f:
    data = f.read().splitlines()
    data = [list(map(int, i.split(','))) for i in data]
    print(data)
```

Output:

```
[[6, 1, 2, -10], [1, 5, 0, -2], [2, 0, 6, 3], [-10, -2, 3, 5]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.genfromtxt()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and read it into a `numpy.ndarray`:

```
import numpy as np
g = np.genfromtxt('test.txt', delimiter=",")

print(g)
#array([[  6.,   1.,   2., -10.],
#       [  1.,   5.,   0.,  -2.],
#       [  2.,   0.,   6.,   3.],
#       [-10.,  -2.,   3.,   5.]])
```

And if you prefer it as a list of lists, you can call `tolist()`:

```
print(g.tolist())
#[[6.0, 1.0, 2.0, -10.0],
# [1.0, 5.0, 0.0, -2.0],
# [2.0, 0.0, 6.0, 3.0],
# [-10.0, -2.0, 3.0, 5.0]]
```

Comment: This is good, assumes `numpy`; it's a great library, but for _just_ reading a matrix is an overkill.

Comment: I suppose that it depends on the end goal, but whenever I see "matrix" I think of numpy. Not saying it's the best solution, but it could be useful. @9000

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `pandas` to read and process csv files:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('file.csv', names=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])
```

Output:

```
   col1  col2  col3  col4
0     6     1     2   -10
1     1     5     0    -2
2     2     0     6     3
3   -10    -2     3     5
```

You can also turn the resulting `DataFrame` to a matrix using:

```
pd.read_csv('tmp.txt', names=['col1','col2','col3','col4']).as_matrix()
```

Output:

```
array([[  6,   1,   2, -10],
       [  1,   5,   0,  -2],
       [  2,   0,   6,   3],
       [-10,  -2,   3,   5]])
```